# Pass through component functions in an external library

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem. I want to use an external library within my app component. When initializing the external library, I can also tell it what to do when an action is triggered. Unfortunately, I don't know how to execute the component functions inside the external library.

Here is the stripped down code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PullToRefresh from 'pulltorefreshjs';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.loadAjaxData = this.loadAjaxData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAjaxData();

    PullToRefresh.init({
      mainElement: 'main',
      onRefresh() {
        this.loadAjaxData();
        }
      },
    });
  }

  loadAjaxData(){
    axios.get("https://localhost/api/").then(response => {
      const data = response.data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header/>
          <main>
            <h2>Headline</h2>
            <p>Conten</p>
          </main>
      </>
    ) 
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get an error when the `loadAjaxData()` function is called.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.loadAjaxData is not a function
    at Object.onRefresh (eval at hmrApply (HMRRuntime.js:244), <anonymous>:46:16)
    at index.umd.js:232
```

Does anyone know a solution? I already read the article "Integrating with Other Libraries" on the Reactjs website, but unfortunately that still doesn't get me anywhere.

Thank u!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Sry, my first question here. Edited the question with the error.

Comment: You have extra closing curly brace inside `PullToRefresh.init`. Try to remove it and see if the error is gone.

Comment: Sadly that only changes the error to ```Uncaught TypeError: this.loadAjaxData is not a function
    at Object.onRefresh (App.js:36)
    at index.umd.js:232```

Comment: loadAjaxData() should be a function, use arrow or function keyword : loadAjaxData=()=>{...}

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change the error. The function does not seem to be available within the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your componentDidMount to :

```
componentDidMount() {
    const that = this ;
    that.loadAjaxData();

    PullToRefresh.init({
      mainElement: 'main',
      onRefresh() {
        that.loadAjaxData(); // <-- this line need that
        }
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank u @babak-yaghoobi that worked great!